# Performing GET in TFS 2013 Server workspace (2013) by non-owner

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS 2013 workspace configured as follows:

[image: dialog showing TFS server location and Public Workspace permissions]

Running a `tf get *` as the workspace owner works fine, however if I try as another user the following is returned:

> TF400033: The operation could not be completed because a local
>   workspace is required to perform this action, but the workspace 
>   COMPUTERNAME;DOMAIN\USERNAME is not a local workspace.

When the workspace is configured as a local workspace, other users are indeed able to run a `tf get *` without any problems.

However I would really like to use a server workspace for the following reasons:

- It's a large workspace - not quite 50,000 items but not far off
- Items are readonly by default - which will help prevent inadvertent changes

I could switch the workspace owner, or the account I need to use to run the `tf get *`, but the question I'd really like to ask is:

**Is it possible (as the image infers) to have "Public Workspace" permissions in the "Server" location?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this IS possible, but I had to perform a couple of steps!

First, I changed the workspace *OWNER* using the Visual Studio dialog (Manage Workspaces).  This immediately allowed other accounts to run `tf get` for SOME mappings, but then for others I'd get the following error:

> TF14061: The workspace SERVER;OLDUSERNAME does not exist.

To overcome the above, simply run:

```
tf workspaces /s:http://YOURTFSSERVER:8080/tfs
```

TFS - Totally Freaky Sometimes.